# Copy a resource file with maven located at the root of the project

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

So, my pom.xml has the following:

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>.</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>.settings/</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/</exclude>
                    <exclude>target/</exclude>
                    <exclude>.classpath</exclude>
                    <exclude>.gitignore</exclude>
                    <exclude>.project</exclude>
                    <exclude>logging.log</exclude>
                    <exclude>mvn_cmd.bat</exclude>
                    <exclude>pom.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
       ...
```

My goal is to copy a single file(e.g. `config.properties`) located at the root of my project and copy it into target/classes when I do a `Maven > Update` with Eclipse. So far the only way I found to fix this issue is to manually exclude all the files from from my `${basedir}` directory.

I believe this can be done directly rather easily with the maven native command, but I need to get this working with **m2eclipse** as well.

I figured the best way to do this, would be a regex to exclude everything but my `config.properties`, but I don't known if maven has this kind of feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using includes instead of excludes, and note that the directory is the root of the project, like this:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>config.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
<resources>
```

Comment: The include works fine if I do a `mvn resources:resources` on command line, but it doesn't include the config.properties with the m2e plugin when I do a `maven > update` on a project. Maybe it's a bug with the eclipse plugin?

Comment: Could be, I have definitely seen Eclipse & Maven not play well together at times. I typically make sure Maven works on the command line, because then Jenkins/your CI system will typically work as well. You might make sure you have an updated version of m2e.

Comment: this and @antogerva answer copies the resources from the root into the classes folder, but how to make maven copy them into the root of the target ?